# Question about mouse and keyboard events in python

Tags: python, pynput

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller as KeyboardController
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller as MouseController
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

keyboard = KeyboardController()
mouse = MouseController()

def on_press(key):
    if key.char == 'q':
        print(mouse.position)
        return True

# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I made this simple script to return the mouse's position if I press the letter q. It works fine until I press something that is not a char, for example, the Enter key. I've been searching around but couldn't find good ways of implementing an if "certain button clicked" to do that. How can I fix this?

Comment: Search on line for button events.  Better yet, work through a tutorial on the associated packages.

Comment: What exactly happens when you press Enter?

Comment: @rcriii I get an error "'Key' object has no attribute 'char'". I tried reading the documentation of "pynput.keyboard" but it doesnt couldnt find a good way of doing it. There should be a simple way to writting that "if" somehow but i not seeing it at all. If i do 
```
 if key == keyboard.pressed('q')
```
nothing happens when I press "q". I tried a bunch of combinations on this "if" but so far nothing worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Try if 'char' in key.__dict__: then check for 'q'.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently, the key object returned to `on_press` does not have a `char` attribute unless you have actually hit a character key. So you have to check for the existence of that attribute. You can do that using [hasattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr):

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller as KeyboardController
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller as MouseController
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

keyboard = KeyboardController()
mouse = MouseController()

def on_press(key):
    if hasattr(key, 'char'):    
        if key.char == 'q':
            print(mouse.position)
            return True

# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```